# How to open a Chrome Packaged App with a parameter on Windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a file handler on my app, I've not Chrome OS so the only way to try my code is to launch the app from command line with a file in parameter. My question is: how?

I've tried 
`chrome --appid=[TheIdOfMyApp] --[Path of the file to open]` but it just opens the app and the entry from my function is the same as when I open Mado with no parameters.

To check if I have an entry I do that :

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(items) { 
  console.log(items);
  // The code to open the app's window...
});
```

It always returns me `Object {isKioskSession: false}`.

[UPDATE]

My manifest looks like (these are just the file handlers and the permissions parts):

```
"file_handlers": {
    "text": {
        "types": ["text/md"],
        "title": "MyApp"
    }
},
"permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries"]},
    {"mediaGalleries": ["read", "allAutoDetected"]},
    "storage",
    "webview"
]
```

[END OF THE UPDATE]

Does anyone know how to check if an app's file handler is working on Windows? Is my code correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should work. Can you provide the manifest of your app?

Comment: I've added the manifest parts who are used for the file handler on the post.

Comment: My guess is the text/md MIME type isn't being interpreted corerctly. Two things to try: (1) what happens if you change your handler to handle all types? (2) is anything appearing on the console after you start the app.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Ben Wells, it's working now. The code (if someone has the same problem one day):

In manifest.json:

```
"file_handlers": {
    "text": {
        "extensions": [
            "md"
        ],
        "title": "YourApp"
    }
},
```

And what to do on the command line (remove `(x86)` if you're on a 32-bit Windows):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app-id=YourAppId "C:\Path\To\document.md"
```

If you want to see if your app has detect a parameter, add the code above (the block who begins with `chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched`) to your background javascript.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot. A word of caution, a fully qualified path is needed (in OSX at least, which is where I'm developing in). Something like this didn't work for me `~/Desktop/file.json`. I had to do `/Users/me/Desktop/file.json`

Answer (score 0):

Command line parameters to packaged apps do not seem to be implemented yet.

The open [issue 165573](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165573) "Allow launch arguments to be passed to platform apps" states "We need to figure out ... if / how to pass these via the command line".

Comment: This is true for random parameters (e.g. --show-foo) but files should be passed through correctly, if your app is setup properly as a file_handler. E.g. the Text app should be able to be started from the command line with a file it can handle.